# Some problem when I tried to use "odein" inside another function

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use "odein" in another function to assess some parameters. But the code gave a sign "restart: shell". I cannot understand what is happenning here.

```py
    def fun(x,ia,ib):
        #### function that returns dy/dt
        def model(y, t, a, b):
            dydt = np.exp(a-b/R/T) 
            return dydt

        #### initial condition
        y0 = 0.0
        #### temperature points
        t = x/d
        #### solve ODEs
        a= ia
        b = ib
        y1 = odeint(modeldydt,y0,t,args=(a,b))
        return y1

    x=array([279,300,310,320,330,340,350])
    y=array([0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.7,0.8])
    calc_model = Model(fun)
    pars = TGA_model.make_params(ia=10, ib=1e4)
    result = calc_model.fit(y, x=x)
```

And what I got is

```
=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
```

I would like to know if it is possible to net the functions together in python. If it is possible, you are very kind to tell me the mistake I have made. If it is not possible, you are still welcome to send me your suggestion. If nothing works in python, I should try some matlab code instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us a list of all the libraries you're including?